# Python 2.7.11 installation in Cygwin

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cygwin

I have an installer which requires python 2.7.11 in particular. The latest cygwin setup contains python 2.7.14 and the 2.7.13 the least. Is there any way out that I can install python 2.7.11 in the cygwin?

Comment: You can check http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html

Comment: Do you think this minor difference in versions could make a difference in an application, unless there is somehow a bug which isn't exposed?

Comment: It would be highly unusual for something to require a specific bugfix release, particularly one like 2.7.11.  What exactly is this "installer" for?

Comment: The installer we use is an internal one,which was written to support only the particular python version. Basically we use the installer, with python 2.7.11 installed in Windows and the execution will be carried out through command prompt. Now, I would like to execute the same in cygwin.